# generic decorators for callable objects with conditional return

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, decorator

I want to write decorator functions for callable objects.

This is what I have now:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename DecoratedT, typename CallableT>
constexpr auto before_callable(DecoratedT &&decorated, CallableT &&callBefore)
{
    return [decorated = std::forward<DecoratedT>(decorated),
            callBefore = std::forward<CallableT>(callBefore)](auto &&...args){

                callBefore(std::as_const(args)...); // TODO: ignore parameters?
                auto &&res = decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
                return res;
                };
}

template <typename DecoratedT, typename CallableT>
constexpr auto after_callable(DecoratedT &&decorated, CallableT &&callAfter)
{
    return [decorated = std::forward<DecoratedT>(decorated),
            callAfter = std::forward<CallableT>(callAfter)](auto &&...args){
                auto &&res = decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
                callAfter(std::as_const(args)...); // TODO: ignore parameters?

                return res;
    };
}

template <typename DecoratedT, typename CallBeforeT, typename CallAfterT>
constexpr auto decorate_callable(DecoratedT &&decorated, 
                                CallBeforeT &&callBefore, 
                                CallAfterT &&callAfter)
{
    return before_callable(after_callable(std::forward<DecoratedT>(decorated), 
                                          std::forward<CallAfterT>(callAfter)),
                            std::forward<CallBeforeT>(callBefore));
}
```

This code works while a `decorated` object has a return type which is not `void`. Error otherwise:

```
<source>:21:24: error: forming reference to void
   21 |                 auto &&res = decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
      |                        ^~~
```

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename SumT>
void print(const SumT& sum)
{
    const auto &res = sum(4, 811);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    struct {
        int operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const
        {
            std::cout << "summing\n"; 
            return lhs + rhs;
        }
    } sum{};

    const auto &printBefore = [](const int lhs, const int rhs, const auto &...){
        std::cout << "Before sum (args): " << lhs << " " << rhs << std::endl;
    };

    const auto &printAfter = [](const auto &...){
        std::cout << "After sum" << std::endl;
    };

    std::cout << "Undecorated: ";
    print(sum);
    std::cout << "\nDecorated Before:\n";
    print(before_callable(sum, printBefore));

    std::cout << "\nDecorated After:\n";
    print(after_callable(sum, printAfter));

    std::cout << "\nDecorated Before and After:\n";
    print(decorate_callable(sum, printBefore, printAfter));

    struct {
        void operator()() const {}
    } retVoid{};

    const auto &voidDecorated = decorate_callable(retVoid, 
                                    [](const auto &...){}, 
                                    [](const auto &...){});
    // voidDecorated(); // does not compile

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x94ehTq17

1. What is a simple and optimization-friendly way of handling `void` return type from a `decorated` object?
2. How can I optionally ignore arguments for lambdas where I don't need them? Using variadic lambdas is a one way, but it is enforced on the user side.
3. Should I use `decltype(auto)` for return in function declarations?

Comment: You can wrap the `callAfter` into a local object that will call it in the destructor. That will delay the execution till after `decorated` returns.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow this is actually a great idea! You can post it as an aswer with example code and I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the SCOPE_EXIT macro from Andrei Alexandrescus talk about Declarative Control Flow. The trick here is that SCOPE_EXIT creates an object with a lambda (the following block) and executes the lambda in the destructor. This delays the execution until the control flow exits the block.

SCOPE_EXIT will always execute the code, SCOPE_SUCCESS will only execute the code if no exception is thrown and SCOPE_FAIL will execute the code only when an exception is thrown.

Note: the original decorator didn't execute the callAfter when an exception is thrown.

```
#include <utility>
#include <exception>

#ifndef CONCATENATE_IMPL
#define CONCATENATE_IMPL(s1, s2) s1##s2
#endif
#ifndef CONCATENATE
#define CONCATENATE(s1, s2) CONCATENATE_IMPL(s1, s2)
#endif

#ifndef ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE
#ifdef __COUNTER__
#define ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(str) CONCATENATE(str, __COUNTER__)
#else
#define ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(str) CONCATENATE(str, __LINE__)
#endif
#endif

template <typename FunctionType>
class ScopeGuard {
  FunctionType function_;
public:
  explicit ScopeGuard(const FunctionType& fn) : function_(fn) { }
  explicit ScopeGuard(const FunctionType&& fn) : function_(std::move(fn)) { }
  ~ScopeGuard() noexcept {
    function_();
  }
};

enum class ScopeGuardOnExit { };

template <typename Fun>
ScopeGuard<Fun> operator +(ScopeGuardOnExit, Fun&& fn) {
  return ScopeGuard<Fun>(std::forward<Fun>(fn));
}
#define SCOPE_EXIT \
  auto ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(SCOPE_EXIT_STATE) \
  = ScopeGuardOnExit() + [&]()

template <typename DecoratedT, typename CallableT>
constexpr auto after_callable(DecoratedT &&decorated, CallableT &&callAfter)
{
    return [decorated = std::forward<DecoratedT>(decorated),
            callAfter = std::forward<CallableT>(callAfter)](auto &&...args){
                SCOPE_EXIT {
                    callAfter(std::as_const(args)...); // TODO: ignore parameters?
                };
                auto &&res = decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);

                return res;
    };
}
```

Comment: this introduces a dependency on `SCOPE_EXIT` which is not a part of a standard library and requires including the header into the project. Can you add an example that does not rely on usage of macros or 3rdparty? Just standard C++ (and/or std lib)

Comment: I reduced it but I'm leaving the macro because it's horrible to use without it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Sorry, still don't like it.  We should not be encouraging use of macros, period, especially tricksy ones like these.

Comment: @PaulSanders you can alway just "gcc -E" the code to remove them.

Comment: @goswin Please make some kind of edit to your answer.  That will enable me to reverse my downvote (I decided I was being a bit mean).

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on a Goswin's suggestion I came up with a shorter and a cleaner version:

```
template <typename DecoratedT, typename CallableT>
constexpr decltype(auto) after_callable(DecoratedT &&decorated, CallableT &&callAfter)
{
    return [decorated = std::forward<DecoratedT>(decorated),
            callAfter = std::forward<CallableT>(callAfter)](auto &&...args){

                const auto &callOnExit = [&](){
                    callAfter(std::as_const(args)...); // TODO: ignore parameters?
                };

                struct on_exit {
                    decltype(callOnExit) onExit;
                    ~on_exit() { !bool(std::uncaught_exceptions()) ? onExit() : void();}
                } onExit{callOnExit};

                return decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Variadic capture is abailable only from C++20 (this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496358/c-lambdas-how-to-capture-variadic-parameter-pack-from-the-upper-scope) was useful). However, since `callOnExit` *doesn't outlive* (correct me if I am wrong) the wrapping lambda's arguments, it is safe to capture all the arguments by reference.
https://godbolt.org/z/dEq19EjWo

---

A naive way is to check return type with `if constexpr`

```
template<typename DecoratedT, typename CallableT>
    constexpr decltype(auto) before_callable(DecoratedT &&decorated, CallableT &&callBefore)
    {
        return [decorated = std::forward<DecoratedT>(decorated),
                callBefore = std::forward<CallableT>(callBefore)](auto &&...args) {
            callBefore(std::as_const(args)...);   // TODO: ignore parameters?
            return decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        };
    }

    template<typename DecoratedT, typename CallableT>
    constexpr decltype(auto) after_callable(DecoratedT &&decorated, CallableT &&callAfter)
    {
        return [decorated = std::forward<DecoratedT>(decorated),
                callAfter = std::forward<CallableT>(callAfter)](auto &&...args) {
            constexpr auto ret_type_is_void =
                std::is_void_v<decltype(decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))>;

            if constexpr (!ret_type_is_void)
            {
                auto &&res = decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
                callAfter(std::as_const(args)...);   // TODO: ignore parameters?
                return res;
            }
            else
            {
                decorated(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
                callAfter(std::as_const(args)...);   // TODO: ignore parameters?
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Is that naive?  Seems fine to me, but you might explain that you need that `else` to prevent the compiler from trying to compile the code that follows it when the return type is `void`.

Comment: @PaulSanders  Goswin has suggested a very elegant solution. This one is very verbose and is C++17 dependent (regardles of this question being tagged for `C++17`)

Comment: Hmmm, maybe.  Can't say I like all those macros very much.  And using `if constexpr` is fine.  As you say, it's from C++17 on only, but that's obviously no problem here.  Personally, I don't like solutions that jump through hoops to support older language that the OP (and probably 99% of the rest of us) don't need.

Comment: You should mention that `!bool(std::uncaught_exceptions())` means you only call `callAfter` when no exception happened. But it certainly is shorter. My code is made so you can have multiple delayed statements in a block, which really isn't needed for this use case. Saves a ton of macro magic. If you don't want to use the SCOPE_EXIT macro at other places (like I do) this solution is preferable.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I took exceptions under consideration after you mentioned `SCOPE_SUCCESS`. When one writes a decorator "by hand" (adding actions after decorated call) if an unhandled exception is thrown, `callAfter` will not be invoked, unless one explicitly wants to handle it in a decorator. So *not calling* `callAfter` on exception by default is equivalent to a "hand-written" decorator. If one wants to catch an exception, he will make a wrapper.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow also in `if constexpr` version `callAfter` will not be executed on exception