# How to correctly forward and use a nested tuple of constexpr struct with standard tuple operations

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, c++20, constexpr

I want to store passed data via `constexpr` `constructor` of a `struct`, and store the data in a `std::tuple`, to perform various TMP / compile time operations.

**Implementation**

```
template <typename... _Ts>
struct myInitializer {
    std::tuple<_Ts...> init_data;

    constexpr myInitializer(_Ts&&... _Vs) 
        : init_data{ std::tuple(std::forward<_Ts>(_Vs)...) }
    {}
};
```

Stored data uses a lightweight `strong type` struct, generated via lvalue and rvalue helper overload:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct data_of_t {
    using type = T;
    using data_t = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    data_t data;

    constexpr data_of_t(Ts&&... _vs)
        : data(std::forward<Ts>(_vs)...)
    {}
};
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto data_of(Ts&&... _vs) {
    return data_of_t<T, Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(_vs)...);
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto data_of(Ts&... _vs) {
    return data_of_t<T, Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(_vs)...);
};
```

It's implemented like

```
template <typename T = int>
class test {
public:
    static constexpr auto func(int p0=0, int p1=1, int p2=3) noexcept {
        return data_of <test<T>>
            (data_of<test<T>>(p0, p1));
    }
};
```

```
int main() {
    constexpr // fails to run constexpr // works without
    auto init = myInitializer (
        test<int>::func()
        ,test<int>::func(3)
        ,test<int>::func(4,5)
    );

    std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {
        //std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        auto merged_tuple = std::tuple_cat(std::forward<decltype(args.data)>(args.data)...);
        }
        , init.init_data);
}
```

**Getting to the point**

std::tuple_cat fails if myInitializer instance is `constexpr`.

```
std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {
        auto merged_tuple = std::tuple_cat(std::forward<decltype(args.data)>(args.data)...);
```

It appears to be related to the `const` qualifier added via `constexpr`.

How can this be fixed?

See full example at https://godbolt.org/z/j5xdT39aE

Comment: You don't need the `data_of(Ts&... _vs)` overload. The `data_of(Ts&&... _vs)` already takes care of it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot this is indeed a left over of experimenting w/o constexpr, to work around an internal compiler error in MSVC.

Comment: Also `_Ts` and `_Vs` are reserved name, you can't use them in any scope, they are reserved for the standard implementation

Comment: AFAICT, std::forward SHOULD (almost) always be used only when cooperating with [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), which is related to [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) and [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing). That's how std::foward [works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward): infer the value category by reverse reasoning from rules of template argument deduction and reference collapsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition of the forwarding problem denoted by Barry, there's a different reason why you cannot have constexpr on `init`. This is because you contain a reference to a temporary inside `data_of_t`.

You see, you are containing a type obtained from overload resolution from a forwarding reference:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto data_of(Ts&&... _vs) {
    return data_of_t<T, Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(_vs)...);
};
```

The `Ts...` in this case could be something like `int, float const&, double&`. You send those reference type and then you contain them inside of the `std::tuple` in  `data_of_t`.

Those temporaries are local variables from the `test` function:

```
template <typename T = int>
class test {
public:
    static constexpr auto func(int p0=0, int p1=1, int p2=3) noexcept {
        return data_of <test<T>>
            (data_of<test<T>>(p0, p1));
    }
};
```

The problem here is that `p0`, `p1`, `p2` are all local variable. You send them in `test_of_t` which will contain references to them, and you return the object containing all those reference to the local variable. This is maybe the cause of the MSVC crash. Compiler are required to provide diagnostic for any undefined behaviour in constexpr context. This crash is 100% a compiler bug and you should report it.

So how do you fix that?

Simply don't contain references by changing `data_of`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto data_of(Ts&&... _vs) {
    return data_of_t<T, std::decay_t<Ts>...>(std::forward<Ts>(_vs)...);
};
```

This will decay the type thus removing the references and decay any reference to C array to pointers.

Then, you have to change your constructor. You call `std::forward` in there but it's no forwarding occurring if you decay in the template arguments.

```
template<typename... Vs> requires((std::same_as<std::decay_t<Vs>, Ts>) && ...)
constexpr data_of_t(Vs... _vs)
    : data(std::forward<Vs>(_vs)...)
{}
```

This will add proper forwarding and also constrain it properly so it always do as `data_of` intended.

Just doing those change will remove UB from the code, but also change it a bit. The type `data_of_t` will always contain values, and won't contain references. If you want to send a reference, you will need something like `std::ref`, just like `std::bind` have to use to defer parameters.

You will still need to use `std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg).data` for proper forwarding as @Barry stated

Answer (score 5):

This:

```cpp
auto merged_tuple = std::tuple_cat(std::forward<decltype(args.data)>(args.data)...);
```

is not the right way to forward data. `decltype(args.data)` is going to give you the type of that data member - which is not a function of either the const-ness or value category of `args`. Let's take a simpler example:

```cpp
void f(auto&& arg) {
    g(std::forward<decltype(arg.data)>(arg.data));
}

struct C { int data; };

C c1{1};
const C c2{2};

f(c1); 
f(c2);
f(C{3});
```

So here I have three calls to `f` (which call `f<C&>`, `f<const C&>`, and `f<C>`, respectively). In all three cases, `decltype(arg.data)` is... just `int`. That's what the type of `C::data` is. But that's *not* how it needs to be forwarded (it won't compile for `c2` because we're trying to cast away const-ness -- as in your example -- and it'll erroneously move out of `c1`).

What you want is to forward `arg`, separately, and *then* access data:

```cpp
void f(auto&& arg) {
    g(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg).data);
}
```

Now, `decltype(arg)` actually varies from instantiation to instantiation, which is a good indicator that we're doing something sensible.

Comment: More on the dark arts of parameter packs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49902823/4641116